# Sending list of objects with MultipartFile field return 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring-boot, multipartfile

I'm trying to send list of objects to api (Spring Boot), where model has MultiPartFile field and description field, but server every time return me `415 Unsupported Media Type`. I'm using Angular 9 on frontend to send data.

My Java DTO object looks like:

```
public class FooRequestDTO {

    private String description;

    private MultipartFile file;

    // getters.. setters..

}
```

My endpoint controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/foo", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
public void upload(@RequestBody List<FooRequestDTO> FooRequestDTOList) {
   // something
}
```

And my method in service in Angular:

```
upload(files: FileInfo[]): Observable<void> {
   const formData = new FormData();
   for (var i = 0; i < files.length;i++) {
     formData.append(`description[]`, files[i].description);
     formData.append(`file[]`, files[i].file);
   }
   return this.http.post<void>(`/foo`, formData);
}
```

I also try sending `files` object directly but it change nothing.
`FileInfo` has only `File file` and `string description` fields.

Is any solution to resolve my problem? In the Internet I didn't find any similiar problem.

Comment: try setting `content-type` header as as `multipart/form-data` while posting the request.

Comment: @SKumar server throw me exception `the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found`

Comment: [a baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/sprint-boot-multipart-requests), [(all possible) @RequestMethod parameters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments), [a sample with multiple files](https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-upload-multiple-files/)

Comment: you have multiple options(!), but the server side "should work" and the client side should "comply"!

Comment: @xerx593 I saw this arcticles. Problem is that I have the list of objects and these examples doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to add below header details in the request to work this.

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=12345
```

Comment: Someone suggested it in comment, but result is the same.

Comment: what is the error are you getting now after adding boundry?

Comment: Same, 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: are you able to test your api from postman? if yes what are the header values are you passing?

Answer (score 0):

First modify api method to handle List of formdata/only formdata.
If List of formdata objects means your api is correct but angular code is incorrect.
If only single formdata object means both are incorrect.

For only single formdata object modify the api code as below:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/foo", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
public void upload(@RequestBody FooRequestDTO FooRequestDTOList) {
   // something
}
```

At angular:
If only single formdata object is sent modify code as below:

```
upload(files: FileInfo[]): Observable<void> {
   const formData = new FormData();
   for (var i = 0; i < files.length;i++) {
     formData.append(`description`, files[i].description);
     formData.append(`file`, files[i].file);
   }
   return this.http.post<void>(`/foo`, formData);
}
```

If multiple formdata objects sent means modify code as below:
If only single formdata object is sent modify code as below:

```
upload(files: FileInfo[]): Observable<void> {
   const formData = new FormData();
   for (var i = 0; i < files.length;i++) {
     formData.append(`description`, files[i].description);
     formData.append(`file`, files[i].file);
   }
   return this.http.post<void>(`/foo`, [formData]);
}
```